# Creating a new attribute/column with dplyr in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame with two attributes x and y: `x<-c(909,446,563,56,888)`and
 `y<-c(676,353,242,181,780)`
Now, I'm trying to use dplyr to create a third column `xy` with entries that are the averages of `x` and `y` at each data point. 
I have the following code to obtain the third variable:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(x,y, na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, I am not getting what I expect. Kindly assit.

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(xy = rowMeans(.[c('x', 'y')], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you